# Terminology - entry point, data source, sink

Tags: appsec, terminology

In the context of application security, I often heard the terms **entry point**, **data source** and **sink**.
Can you define them for me in simple terms please?

Answer (score 4):

Source and sink are used in a data flow analysis. The source is where data comes from, the sink is where it ends. With regards to application security, source and sink are frequently used for [taint analysis](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Static_Code_Analysis#Taint_Analysis).

Data is "tainted" if it comes from an insecure *source* such as a file, the network, or the user. Any data that touches data also becomes tainted. If tainted data is ever passed to a sensitive *sink*, then static analysis will flag an issue. For example, if user input from a web form is printed, unescaped, into a log file, then a static analysis tool will report a [log forging vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Log_Forging).

I think that [entry point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point) is a more general term that refers to the place where a program or event handler begins execution. For example, the `main()` function of a C program or the [doGet()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)) function of an `HttpServlet`. This is the starting point for data flow analysis.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer. If data is passed between multiple functions func1 -> func2 -> func3. Are all functions in this path, sinks?

Comment: Generally, sink is the end of the data flow. In the context of security static analysis, sinks are the operations that must have clean data. A sink could be a database call or returning data to the browser. Anything that you wouldn't want an attacker to be able to fully manipulate. You use *sanitizing* operations to escape or filter tainted data. After sanitization, tainted data becomes clean and can safely enter a sink